# React native for windows desktop app run very slow

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

I'm trying to create a desktop windows app using [react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native) (0.64.2) & [react-native-windows](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-windows) (0.64.20). But when I'm trying to run the app the running finishes after several minutes (> 50min).

Visual Studio: Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0

These are the specs of my computer:

- OS: Windows 10 10.0.19042
- CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ
- CPU @ 2.60GHz Memory: 11.89 GB

This duration is normal according to my computer specs? What can I do to make it faster?